# Retaining strong typing with an optional parameter

Tags: typescript, prisma

I use `prisma` for all of my database logic, and I've come to rely on the typing of the data it fetches from the database downstream.

Currently, I'm using predefined `select` fields to ensure that the returned data is typed to contain exactly the fields within it.

I've been asked to add the ability to specify your own `select` when calling a function. Is there a way to support this *without* losing the typing of the returned data?

Here's what I've been working on thus far:

```
const listAllTypes = <T extends Prisma.UserTypeSelect>(select?: T) => {
  return select === undefined
    ? prisma.userType.findMany({ select: { name: true, description: true } })
    : prisma.userType.findMany({ select });
};

const test = async () => {
  const x = await listAllTypes();
  const y = await listAllTypes({ name: true });
};
```

In this snippet, both `x` and `y` have a union type. `x` is: `{ name: string; description: string; }[] | {}[]` and `y` is `{ name: string; description: string; }[] | { name: string; }[]`.

Is there a way to make the return type of `x` *only* `{name: string, description: string}` and the return type of `y` *only* `{name: string }`? I was hoping that narrowing on `select === undefined` would be sufficient, but it would seem not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that straightforward though:

```
model User {
  id    String @id @default(uuid())
  email String @unique
}
```

You can create something like this:

```
function listAllTypes<S extends Prisma.UserSelect>(
  select?: Prisma.Subset<S, Prisma.UserSelect>
) {
  if (select) {
    return prisma.user.findMany<
      { select: S } & Omit<Prisma.UserFindManyArgs, 'select' | 'include'>
    >({ select })
  } else {
    return prisma.user.findMany()
  }
}
```

This will give you what you were looking for.